# editingFinished of QlineEdit is emited a second time when a dialog is executed in the editingFinshed event

Tags: python, pyqt

When I connect the signal `editingFinished` of a `QLineEdit` to a function which inclued the execution of a `QDialog`, the signal `editingFinished` of the `QLineEdit` is emited a second time. That introduction doens't look very clear... The next example should help you to understand :

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import sys

class Foo(QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.editingFinished.connect(self.editingFinishedEvent)

    def editingFinishedEvent(self):
        dialog = QDialog()
        dialog.exec_()
        print('editing finished event occured !')

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

win = Foo()
win.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

That script create and show a `QLineEdit`. When I edit the value of that `QLineEdit` and press enter, the method `editingFinishedEvent` should be executed ONCE. It's the case if I remove the line `dialog.exec_()`. But If I don't, `editingFinishedEvent` is executed twice instead of once.

Comment: See Also: [Report in official Qt forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/105335/qlineedit-editingfinished-called-twice-if-press-enter-key-actual-bug/4) where another workaround and a bug ID are present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `editingFinished` signal is emitted, when the return or enter key is pressed or the line edit loses the focus [see documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#editingFinished). by `editingFinishedEvent` the focus changes from the line edit to the dialog and the signal is emitted a second time. You can use `returnPressed` signal instead. It is only emitted, when the return or enter key is pressed.

Answer (score 2):

I think one can disconnect the slot before launching the dialog, and re-connect afterwards:

```
class Foo(QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.editingFinished.connect(self.editingFinishedEvent)

    def editingFinishedEvent(self):
        # disconnect
        self.editingFinished.disconnect()
        dialog = QDialog()
        dialog.exec_()
        # re-connect
        self.editingFinished.connect(self.editingFinishedEvent)
```

This way, either focus-out or return-pressing will trigger the slot, but only once.